# Revert permission of /usr back to root

Tags: permissions, chown

I was doing some alterations but in one I messed up.

I changed the permissions of almost everything inside the `/usr` folder to my own user. It didn't change everything because it failed in the middle of the execution, I still have `/sbin`, `/share` and `/src` assigned to root.

the command I ran was this **(this was executed while inside /usr)**:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:myuser .
```

Is there any way for me to revert this?

If I run:

```
sudo chown -R root:root .
```

I get this error:

`sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`

Comment: I would advice a re-install without formatting.

Comment: That is what I'm thinking. But just before I go and do that I thought I'd come here for a better solution if there is one.

Comment: You should be able to fix this in a single user session by booting into recovery mode.  [See this document](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), follow the instructions to get a root prompt and remount your root partition as read-write, and then you should be able to `cd /usr` and `chown -R root:root .`

Comment: "Better" well... you could manually fix /usr/bin and /usr/bin/sudo and anything else that throws an error. But,unless you want to do that as a learning exercise, I would not waste time and just reinstall (without formatting)

Comment: @rocketman10404 not everting in /usr/bin is root:root :) (chage is root:shadow  bsd-write is root:tty crontab is root:crontab Not sure if it matters though ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind you are correct, and actually I'll bet the distinction is quite important.  Re-installing is probably best route for a safe, long-term solution.

Comment: You know ... this is a "problem" with apt ( Debian / Ubuntu ). in rpm systems it is possible to recover, see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reset-rhel-centos-fedora-package-file-permission.html . Perhaps we could file a bug report or a feature request to enable restoration on .deb systems? I am not sure how much interest there would be from the developers.

Comment: There is a bash script that might help - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49959/how-to-restore-default-group-user-ownership-of-all-files-under-var .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just chown -R the /usr partition, because not everything in that partition is owned by root. It sucks, you'll have to reinstall everything, but the only safe solution is to do a reinstall or recover from a backup.

Answer (score 1):

It does suck to do a complete re-install. that is certainly one option. However, most of the files in /usr/bin ARE root:root. These are the only ones which aren't:

```
-rwsr-sr-x  1 daemon daemon     51464 Oct 21  2013 at
-rwxr-sr-x  1 root   shadow     54968 Feb 17 02:42 chage
-rwxr-sr-x  1 root   crontab    35984 Feb  9  2013 crontab
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root   lpadmin    14336 Apr 10 19:40 lppasswd
-rwxr-sr-x  3 root   mail       14592 Dec  3  2012 mail-lock
-rwxr-sr-x  3 root   mail       14592 Dec  3  2012 mail-touchlock
-rwxr-sr-x  3 root   mail       14592 Dec  3  2012 mail-unlock
-rwxr-sr-x  1 root   mlocate    39520 Jun 20  2013 mlocate
-rwxr-sr-x  1 root   ssh       284784 May 12 17:04 ssh-agent
-rwxr-sr-x  1 root   tty        19024 Apr 16 17:07 wall
```

for a standard install. 
In /usr/sbin it's:

```
-rwsr-xr--  1 root    dip      343168 Jan 22  2013 pppd
-rwsr-sr-x  1 libuuid libuuid   18904 Apr 16 17:07 uuidd
```

in /usr/lib/

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root utempter     4096 May  7 23:46 utempter
```

in  /usr/local/share

```
 drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff 4096 Aug 20  2013 ca-certificates
 drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff 4096 Aug 20  2013 fonts
 drwxrwsr-x  7 root staff 4096 May  8 17:11 sgml
 drwxrwsr-x  6 root staff 4096 May  8 17:11 xml
```

and in /usr/local/lib any python directories, e.g:

```
 drwxrwsr-x  4 root staff 4096 May  8 18:44 python2.7
```

Comment: obviously if you have installed lots of additional software, there may be others - but if you re-install without formatting it won't fix those anyway